# confirmation popup window on jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have delete link which onclick calls js function which process further with delete action.
I want to implement confirmation dialog window which popups on delete link and process to js function on ok confirmation.

*It is jquery mobile web app.*

```
<a onclick="DeleteRecord(@rec.ID);" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simplest way to do that would be something like:

```
<a onclick="if (confirm('Delete record?')) DeleteRecord(@rec.ID);" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true">
```

But It would be much cleaner to separate your javascript from your markup.